# Connecting two path strings to get the final path?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vb.net-2010, vba

I'm trying to save excel file into a specific path. 
So basically, when I click the button, I'm creating a folder, and want to save the file inside that folder. 
The created folder has the current month as name. I'm trying to save into that current month folder.

```
    'Create folder as Month Name. Save filename as date inside "month".
    Dim sDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss")
    Dim sMonth As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")
    Dim sFolder = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\Excel\"


    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))

    Dim sfinal = Path.Combine(sFolder, sMonth)
    xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sDate) & ".xlsx")

    xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
```

As it is, this code doesn't give me any errors. But instead of creating a folder named "March" <-current month and saving inside it, it saves the file in \Excel\ and it also creates folder in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long hours of excruciating pain, I've finally did it!
Apparently I was missing an "\"
Since "sMonth" became dynamic name, which later I wanted to use as path, and save files in that folder. I needed to simply put that "\" after sMonth, to tell it to save inside it.

Before I realize this... I've broken down, simplified the code as much as I could so I can logically connect the pieces. What I ended up with, is something slightly different. Now the SaveAS properly saves the file inside the new folder.

```
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss")

    Dim sMonth As String
    sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")

    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = sDate + ".xlsx"

    Dim sFolder As String
    sFolder = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\Excel\"


    Dim sfinal As String
    sfinal = (sFolder & sMonth & "\") '<- this thingie here o.O

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))

    xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))

    xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

you could use the following function (similar to .NET System.IO.Path.Combine)

```
Function PathCombine(path1 As String, path2 As String)

    Dim combined As String

    combined = path1
    If Right$(path1, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        combined = combined & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    combined = combined & path2
    PathCombine = combined

End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do note that the above is only valid for **excel** (which the question is tagged with), in case you end up on this page (like me) searching for VBA path separator in **powerpoint**

Answer (score 1):

I find this method to be much easier.

Create a `FileSystemObject` and use `BuildPath` Method, like so:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
skPath = fs.BuildPath(ActiveDocument.Path, "Survival Story of Sword King")
```

**Attention**:  `ActiveDocument.Path` is current directory in Word and does not work in excel or other.  for excel it would be `ActiveWorkbook.Path`

My point is some methods or namespace are application specific.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to actually be setting the save path to the created directory. Instead, I believe you're appending the month to the beginning of the file name in the xlSh.SaveAs(sFinal & Format(sDate) & ".xlsx"). Basically (though I'm not sure of the specific command) you need to navigate to the folder you created after you create it. *Probably* something to the format of

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.ChangeDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))
```

though I don't know that that specific command actually exists as I wrote it.

Comment: Trust me, I've tried... I tried so many combinations while referencing to the line you posted, and I couldn't get it working...

Comment: Can you run it again and have it print out the values of each variable at the time each variable is used? That way we can see what is being input into the system.

Comment: Don't know. We do know where the problem is... It's this code:     Dim sfinal = Path.Combine(sFolder, sMonth)
    xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sDate) & ".xlsx")  I just don't know of any other way to SaveAs

Comment: Glad you got it working! I was asking for the output as I was wondering about that ending slash, but sounds like you got it on your own, congrats!

Comment: Oh, on a another thingie.... How to check if directory exists simply save the file, if it doesn't, then create the folder and save the file inside it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480389/excel-vba-check-if-directory-exists-error

Something like 

`IF Dir(sFolder & Format(sMonth), vbDirectory) = ""

Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))    

xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))

Else

xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))

End If`

Hopefully that makes sense, I can't seem to separate the lines for the code haha

Comment: Thanks. It works, although I modified it a bit.                                         `If Dir(sFolder, vbDirectory) = sMonth Then

           
            xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))
        Else
            
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))
            
            xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))

        End If`

Comment: Awesome! Always great to tailor others' code to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

To those who have been wondering wtf I was doing with all this, here is the full sub. And if anyone needs something similar. Thanks for the support. Problem has been resolved.

```
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet


    xlApp = New Excel.Application


    xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    xlSh = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)

    'Items from listbox1 to be exported into excel, second row, second column.
    Dim row As Integer = 2
    Dim col As Integer = 2
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        xlSh.Cells(row, col) = ListBox1.Items(i)
        row = row + 1
    Next
    row += 1
    col = 1

    'Items from listbox2 to be exported into excel, second row, third column.
    Dim row2 As Integer = 2
    Dim col2 As Integer = 3
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        xlSh.Cells(row2, col2) = ListBox2.Items(i)
        row2 = row2 + 1
    Next
    row2 += 1
    col2 = 1


    'Create folder as Month Name. Save filename as date inside that folder.

    'Make filename be yyyy-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss")

    'This will be used as name for the new folder.
    Dim sMonth As String
    sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")

    'Filename + extension.
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = sDate + ".xlsx"

    'This is the path.
    Dim sFolder As String
    sFolder = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\Excel\"

    'This is the path combined with sMonth to make the final path.
    Dim sfinal As String
    sfinal = (sFolder & sMonth & "\")

    'Check if folder with the name sMonth already exists.
    If Dir(sFolder, vbDirectory) = sMonth Then

        'If it exist, then simply save the file inside the folder.
        xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))
    Else
        'If it doesn't exist:
        'This is the creation of sMonth folder, inside "\excel\.
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sFolder & Format(sMonth))
        'This saves the excel file at path sfinal, with filename of sFileName
        xlSh.SaveAs(sfinal & Format(sFileName))

    End If



    'Close everything.
    xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I add an upgrade to the @labilbe aswer.

Now, it can take relative paths backwards ("......")

```
Public Function GetAbsolutePath(relativePath As String) As String
    
    Dim absPath As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    
    absPath = ActiveWorkbook.path
    
    ' Make sure paths are in correct format
    relativePath = Replace(relativePath, "/", "\")
    absPath = Replace(absPath, "/", "\")
    
    Do While Left$(relativePath, 3) = "..\"
    
        ' Remove level from relative path
        relativePath = Mid$(relativePath, 4)
        
        ' Remove level from absolute path
        pos = InStrRev(absPath, "\")
        absPath = Left$(absPath, pos - 1)
    
    Loop
     
    GetAbsolutePath = PathCombine(absPath, relativePath)
    
End Function

Function PathCombine(path1 As String, path2 As String)

    Dim combined As String

    combined = path1
    If Right$(path1, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        combined = combined & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    combined = combined & path2
    PathCombine = combined

End Function
```

Example

```
Sub a()
  
 Debug.Print GetAbsolutePath("..\..\..\Compartido\ATEFI\ATEFI EMV.ppt")

End Sub
```

[image]