# Excel VB folder search speed improvement

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a spreadsheet macro with a colleague of mine to manage an action list and manage associated folders and files. We currently have a working script, however now that we have around 150 items on the list its randomly crashing and very slow. I am very new to coding and would like to improve my skills to make my life easier, and make data management easier.

Currently the macro searches through the parent directory folder by folder looking for a match, this seems to be cause of the hang up. I was looking at replacing it with something a little more efficient, such as "Find" or similar, however not sure if this would be best from my research.

Any other tips would be appreciated, this is my first macro and clearly have a lot to learn.

```
Sub END_OF_DAY()
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim aC As Double
Dim colFol As Double
Dim strPath As String
Dim IDPath As String
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fo1
Dim fo2
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim fMatch As Boolean

strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
On Error Resume Next

Set fo1 = fso.GetFolder(strPath & "\Items\")



aC = 0
colFol = 1

For aC = 1 To 100
    If oSht.Cells(10, aC).Value = "ID_FOLDER" Then
        colFol = aC
        Exit For
    End If
Next aC

If colFol = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: Could not find ID_FOLDER column"
    GoTo endth:
End If

aC = 13
While oSht.Cells(aC, 1).Value <> ""
    IDPath = "ID_" & oSht.Cells(aC, 1).Value
    bFound = False

    For Each fo2 In fo1.subfolders
        fMatch = False
        If Left(fo2.Name, Len(IDPath)) = IDPath Then
            If Len(fo2.Name) = Len(IDPath) Then
                fMatch = True
            ElseIf Asc(Mid(fo2.Name, Len(IDPath) + 1, 1)) < 48 Then
                fMatch = True
            ElseIf Asc(Mid(fo2.Name, Len(IDPath) + 1, 1)) > 57 Then
                fMatch = True
            End If
        End If
        If fMatch = True Then
            If oSht.Cells(aC, colFol).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Could not rename folder for ID_" & oSht.Cells(aC,   1).Value & ". Add ID Name to column " & colFol
            Else
                If UCase(fo2.Name) = UCase(oSht.Cells(aC, colFol).Value) Then
                    'do nothing
                Else
                    fo2.Name = oSht.Cells(aC, colFol).Value
                End If
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next fo2

    If bFound = False Then
        If oSht.Cells(aC, colFol).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Could not create folder for ID_" & oSht.Cells(aC, 1).Value & ". Add ID Name to column " & colFol
        Else
            IDPath = strPath & "\Items\" & oSht.Cells(aC, colFol).Value
            fso.CreateFolder IDPath
        End If
    End If

    aC = aC + 1
Wend

strPath = strPath & "\Backup\5A_5B-PER-" & Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) &  Day(Now()) & ".xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strPath


endth:
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than searching the file system for each iteration of your While loop, do that once and save the results in memory (maybe in an array or dictionary), then search that each loop

Comment: And get rid of that evil `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: If your goal is to see if a directory excists use Dir(), to check for existence, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480389/excel-vba-check-if-directory-exists-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I'll let you know how I go.