# Excel to PDF - how to specify where the macro will save the PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, save

I am running this code which basically saves the last row of my excel sheet to PDF file, it saves the PDF file to the folder which the excel sheet and my word template are(they are in the same folder).

**How can I set a different location as a saving point?**
I want to restrict the users to a specific location which is not the folder where the excel sheet and the word template are.

**For example:** I want the files to be saved here : "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder"
Also, please guide me on how to implement it to my code, kinda new to this.

```
Sub RunMerge()
' Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
' Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model to be set, via Tools|References in the VBE.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMPath As String, StrName As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
wdApp.Visible = False
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
StrMMPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrMMDoc = StrMMPath & "MailMergeDocument.doc"
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
With wdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
    i = .DataSource.RecordCount
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        StrName = .DataFields("Name")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        'Add the name to the footer
        '.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore StrName
        '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for then:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF FileName:="sales.pdf" Quality:=xlQualityStandard OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat

Comment: I t hink this code only saves the workbook, but I want to save the PDF into this folder for instance : C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder
The code already saves it as PDF but it directs the file to the folder where the Excel sheet and word template are.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses the variable `strMMPath` as the path here.

```
.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

To change it to a folder on the desktop of the current user, use this

```
Dim SavePath as String

SavePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & "\Desktop\Folder\"
.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

Note: `Environ$("UserName")` returns the name of the currently logged in user

Comment: Environ$("UserName") does that automatically or do I have to insert the name of the currently logged in user?
Also, I have this line of code now :  SavePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & "\Desktop\Folder\Test"
        .SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False

but it doesnt actually save it to the folder named "Test", all it does is saving it to the current folder and adds Test to the name of the file for some reason.

Comment: As I said, `Environ$("UserName")` returns the name of the currently logged in user.  But the whole path has to be valid.  Does the user _always_ have a folder on the desktop called `Folder`?  If not you'll want to check it exists first, and create it if required.  And are you sure you want to call it `Folder`?

Comment: For now I want to call it Folder, ill change it later, how do I do this : "If not you'll want to check it exists first, and create it if required"

Comment: [Check if folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15482073/445425) and [Create a Dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008975)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) - note that that help page is a bit vague, use `MkDir SavePath`

Comment: Any chance you can guide me on how to implement this to my code? I have no idea on where to put the code. consider me as a person with 0 knowledge about this. :/ thanks for the help even if you cant :)

Answer (score 0):

So change:

```
StrMMPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

to point to where you want the file saved. For example:

```
StrMMPath = C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Folder\"
```

It would be nice to see you actually invest some effort in all this. The site from where you got the code even tells you how to make such a change!!! So far, it seems, all you've done in multiple threads is asked to be spoon-fed with solutions and/or modifications to code you've copied from another site.

PS: It's also common courtesy to vote for answers that have helped you.

Comment: To be fair, I have tried to implement it on my own with the answers given to me, but even with trial & error I did not succeed on making it work.
and about the voting part, I have been voting on answers that have helped me but because I have less than 15 reputation it does not show. :/

Comment: I will apply it to my next questions if I have any :)
For this one , I have managed to make it work by making a new module which is dedicated to checking if the folder exists and if not, it will create one. I activate the 2 modules via an ActiveX command button.
This is the code I am using(runs first) :
Sub Path_Exists()
Dim Path As String
Dim Folder As String
Path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\FolderName\"
Folder = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)

If Folder = vbNullString Then
    MkDir "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\FolderName\"
End If
End Sub